# Function return type based on passed in value/Better way to type function return type

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, types, typescript-generics, typescript-types

I've created a few interfaces that reflect a function that potentially returns 3 different objects based on a passed in enumeration, and I'm trying to add typings to the function that returns them.

```
interface SummaryData {
   summary: string,
   summaryData: number
}

interface ConfigurationData {
   configuration: string,
   configurationData: number[]
}

interface StatusData {
   status: string,
   statusData: string
}

enum ViewTypeEnums {
        summary = 1,
        configuration = 2,
        status = 3
}

function getInfo(viewType: ViewTypeEnums): SummaryData | ConfigurationData | StatusData {

  if(viewType == 1){
    return {
      summary: "this is a summary",
      summaryData: 1
      }
  } else if (viewType == 2){
    return {
      configuration: "this is configuration data",
      configurationData: [1,2,3]
      }
  } else {
    return {
      status: "this is status data",
      statusData: "data"
      }
  }

}
```

At the moment I'm using type parameters and pass in the expected return type when I call the function.

I know that I can instead use a type parameter to determine the return type, but it seems a little verbose/redundant to have to specify the expected data twice, and seems like there would be a better/more elegant way.

`getInfo<SummaryData>(1)` vs just having `getInfo(1)` with an inferred return type of `SummaryData`

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the feedback. I've abstracted away all of the external library stuff.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/W4a0Xw) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?